# Django Channels. Adding users to a Group

Tags: django, django-channels

I am coding kind of a social network app. I want to have users create conversations and add their friends to the conversation at creation of the conversation. They are going to receive messages via websocket.

The problem that I have is that I can add users to listen to their conversations upon establishing websocket connection but how do I add a user's `reply_channel` to the `Group` of the newly created by some other user conversation (while the former user already has websocket connection established) so that they could start listening to incoming messages from the conversation?

This is my `consumers.py` in the `conversations` app.

```
from channels import Channel, Group
from channels.sessions import channel_session, enforce_ordering
from channels.auth import channel_session_user, channel_session_user_from_http
from channels.security.websockets import allowed_hosts_only


@allowed_hosts_only
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    user = message.user
    conversation_ids = list(user.conversations.all().values('id'))
    groups = ['_'.join(['conversation', id]) for id in conversation_ids]
    for group in groups:
        Group(group).add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

@channel_session_user
def ws_receive(message):
    pass

@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    user = message.user
    conversation_ids = list(user.conversations.all().values('id'))
    groups = ['_'.join(['conversations', id]) for id in conversation_ids]
    for group in groups:
        Group(group).discard(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
```

I'm planning to submit messages through http requests. These are relevant exempts from my `views.py` from the `conversations` app (this is API view which does not render any html).

```
class MessageView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def put(self, request):
        user = request.user.id
        conversation_id = request.data.get("conversation_id")
        conversation = get_object_or_404(Conversation, id=conversation_id)
        message_params = {
            request.get('message')
        }
        serializer = MessageSerializer(data=message_params)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class ConversationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def put(self, request):
        creator = get_object_or_404(Person, id=request.user.id)
        participants = []
        for participant in request.data.get("participants"):
            participants.append(get_object_or_404(Person, id=participant))
        conversation = create_conversation(creator, *participants)
        serializer = ConversationSerializer(conversation)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I imagined that I would add some code in the `ConversationView` to "subscribe" participants to conversation updates like two lines:

```
for participant in participant:
    Group('conversation_'+conversation.id).add(participant_reply_channel)
```

just before `return`. However, I don't know how to get values for `participant_reply_channel`.

Comment: You'll need to add some code so we can at least try to help. As a rule of thumb, the more specific you can be, the better response you'll receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue recently. Using [django-channels-presence](https://django-channels-presence.readthedocs.io) solved my problem. Users are added to a Room with separate Group. What you want to do is add users to the same room and using their original reply channel generated by daphne(so it is unique for every user) will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed although I ended up implementing a similar feature with plain _redis_ library. I wish you answered it earlier but, still, much appreciated!

Comment: @Mihail Borisov Can you point me toward information on how you accomplished this with plain redis? I'm interested in a similar solution, perhaps where I can query redis for users that can be "connected" into the same custom group.  Thanks in advance. Marco